# Suppervisor - php-fpm leads to 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a web application based on php and nginx images ... Everything works great until I set a command under the PHP configuration:
`command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /symfony/supervisord.conf`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    php:
        build: docker/php
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - '.:/symfony'
        command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /symfony/supervisord.conf

    nginx:
         image: nginx:1.11
         tty: true
         volumes:
             - './public/:/symfony'
             - './docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
         ports:
             - '80:80'
         links:
             - php
```

This is my default.conf

```
server {
 server_name ~.*;

 location / {
     root /symfony;

     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
 }

 location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
     client_max_body_size 50m;

     fastcgi_pass php:9000;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /symfony/public/index.php;
 }

 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

This is my supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true
```

Nginx logs show me:

> nginx_1     | 2018/10/02 00:42:36 [error] 11#11: *1 connect() failed
>   (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   172.23.0.1, server: ~.*, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.23.0.2:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"

As we see, nginx report a 502 Bad Gateway error. If i remove the last line, CMD, everything works fine. If I remove the line and I acess via `docker-compose exec php bash` and launch the command manually everything work also.

Any Idea why adding that command  leads to 502 Bad Gateway ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I've found a solution. The issue was related to Supervisor. Every time we start our Supervisor service, the php-fpm service is automatically stopped. That's why we need to add a configuration that will restart php-fpm, but this time from within the Supervisor configuration.

```
[program:php-fpm]
command = /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: Excellent work by explaining your answer as well. I hope this wont affect performance of php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with similar problem:

Don't forget that `command` key in `docker-compose.yml` file **overrides** default `CMD` in `Dockerfile`, therefore that command won't be run.
For example, if `php:7.4-fpm` final command is `CMD php-fpm`, it won't be run.

Therefore if you have some custom logic for running after container is ran, don't forget to include it in your `command`, e.g.:

```
command: bash -c "php-fpm & npm run dev"
```